# What are my advantages if I deposit gold on my personal bank?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

When visiting the Bank guy for my personal bank, I got an option to deposit my gold there. That seems like a simple feature, but I can't figure out what my advantages are.

Do I have to withdraw my gold evertime I want to visit a vendor? Are there mechanisms where I can lose gold?

**What are my advantages when depositing gold in my personal bank?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't send mail to yourself, but your bank is shared account wide.

As such you can deposit some gold with one character and then retrieve it with another - similar to how the bank allows you to move items between characters.

Deposited items can be accessed directly when crafting.

Deposited money **can't** be accessed directly.

**Edit:**

As of Patch 1.6 ("Update 6"), gold in your bank **won't** be taken by Guards arresting you due to your previous crimes/bounty.